# Cannot initialize the indexer process?

Tags: magento-1.9, price, indexing

I am unable to reindex product prices, it always show the message

> Cannot initialize the indexer process.

Comment: Have you installed any extension Like SCP Because I have same issue with that

Answer (score 4):

**To resolve the "Cannot initialize the indexer process" you need to run follow below step**

> **Solution 1 :-**
>
> This is usually occurred when we Enable "Use Flat Catalog Category"
> and "Use Flat Catalog Product"
>
> Please connect SSH via Putty run below command:-
>
> **These is Individual commands for re-indexing:-**
>
> php shell/indexer.php --reindex catalog_category_flat
>
> php shell/indexer.php --reindex catalog_category_product
>
> php shell/indexer.php --reindex catalogsearch_fulltext
>
> **OR run all re-indexing:-**
>
> php shell/indexer.php --reindexall
>
> Then clear the magento all cache.

**Solution 2 :-**

> Try to run indexing with PHP script file.
> Create a file reindex_custom.php in the root.

```
<?php
require_once("app/Mage.php");
Mage::app('default');
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
try{
$indexerByShell = Mage::getBaseDir().'/shell/indexer.php';
if(file_exists($indexerByShell))  
 { 
$indexListByCode = array(
"catalog_product_attribute",
                       "catalog_product_price",
                       "catalog_product_flat",
                       "catalog_category_flat",
                       "catalog_category_product",
                       "catalog_url",
                       "catalogsearch_fulltext",
                       "cataloginventory_stock"
    );
        //reindex using magento command line  
        foreach($indexListByCode as $indexer)  
        {  
            echo "reindex $indexer \n ";  
            exec("php $indexerByShell --reindex $indexer");  
        } 
    }
}catch(Exception $e){
    echo $e;
}
?>
```

**Then clear the magento all cache and run this file as http://domain.com/reindex_custom.php**

Answer (score 0):

1. Run Indexing from the CLI at the root of your magento installation

   php shell/indexer.php --reindex catalog_product_price
2. Make sure that the var/ folder has the correct file permissions and ownership. Magento needs to write to those folders.
3. Change your memory limit.  Change this in your .htaccess that is located in your site root ini_set('memory_limit','2048M');